# Identity function (for use in forks, eg)

Tags: j

Consider:

```
(i. 5) */ (i. 5)
```

which produces:

```
0 0 0  0  0
0 1 2  3  4
0 2 4  6  8
0 3 6  9 12
0 4 8 12 16
```

Is there an identity function that would, eg, allow me to write that expression with a fork, without repeating `(i. 5)`?

### EDIT

I've answered my own question below, but came upon the answer by luck.  If anyone can offer suggestions for searching J's docs "by function" or by keyword, I'd appreciate it.  In this case, it would have been nice to type "identity" into a documentation search, and see the "Reflexive" operator as a suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could, indeed, use j's identity functions in a fork to achieve the result you asked for. The reflex adverb is more concise, but that's not a fork.

Here's the implementation you originally specified:

```
   ([*/]) i. 5
0 0 0  0  0
0 1 2  3  4
0 2 4  6  8
0 3 6  9 12
0 4 8 12 16
```

A google search *site:jsoftware.com identity* might have worked for you, since you already understood forks.

Answer (score 3):

The "Reflexive" operator `~`, documented [here](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d220v.htm), is exactly what I'm looking for:

```
*/~ i.5
```

In general (from the docs above),

```
u~ y ↔ y u y . For example, ^~ 3 is 27, and +/~ i. n is an addition table.
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a path (however convoluted) from the J [homepage](http://jsoftware.com/) and the approximate result you stumbled upon.

1. first type 'idendity' in the search box on the homepage
2. note the 2nd result mentions something calld "table"
3. return to the search box and search for `table`
4. follow the link result [`D. Function Tables`](http://www.jsoftware.com/docs/help701/phrases/function_tables.htm)
5. note adverb `a8=: ft=: 1 : 'x/~@i.' NB. function table`

Admittedly this takes a bit of luck and persistence to get from point A to point B, and some sort of documentation search would be a welcome addition to J, especially since most of the terms are so hard to search for using normal search engines.